# UIWebView loading plain text

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have this piece of code:

```
     NSString *body = dataItem.body;
        NSData* data=[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if (data) {     
    [webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/plain" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"nil"]];  
                      }

webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

This piece on execution gives this error in my debugger

> Unknown scheme, doing nothing: nil

However if I do this:

```
NSString *webViewBody = [[body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t"       withString:@"&nbsp;"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<pre> %@ </pre>",body];
        [webView loadHTMLString:webViewBody baseURL:nil];

        webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

I am able to see the content in my webView.

I want the first bit to execute. Why is it giving me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"nil"]
```

just creates an invalid NSURL, and trying to load it in the webview is the cause of that error. Just pass `nil` for `baseURL` like you're doing in the second snippet.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am having trouble dealing with opening a url link in safari. When I click a link in UIWebView it opens within itself. I would like to identify url's in the text and redirect the control to safari when a url is clicked in my UIWebView. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please open another question for this problem.